# css: I can't apply background-color

Tags: html, css

I can't set background-color for tr where subtotal placed.

Source http://jsfiddle.net/rPyn8/, check tr row with 'subtotal' it should have #cccccc.

Comment: Please add your code here instead of having it in dropbox.

Comment: Another option is to add the code to a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and linking us to that.

Comment: Please don't add any downloadable sources, instead create your issue in http://jsfiddle.net/ and share it with us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues with this code. First off, the `tr` in question has its `background-color` set on the `style` attribute of the `tr` tag (in the html). Secondly, the child `td` elements also have a `background-color` set, so even if you were able to set the `background-color` of the `tr` element, you still wouldn't see any change because the child `td` elements' `background-color` is on top. To change the background of the child `td` elements:

**Replace**
`.subtotal {background-color:red !important;text-align:right;}`

**With**
`.subtotal td {background-color:red !important;text-align:right;}`

Also, you will notice that the border between the two cells is still the old color. You can fix this by adding the following CSS to `.subtotal td {}`:

```
border-right-color:COLORHERE;
```

Answer (score 4):

td is inside tr, which overrides the tr color. Look at example 1, you'll see it as black since the inner tag is on top (or "inside") of the other one. You'll see the red color if you change the inner div size making both divs visible on example 2.

Examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/35LNb/

Comment: Righto. The `subtotal` td is set to `background-color: #EBF0F2` which is of course overriding the tr colour.

Comment: i see, indeed, but why the higher table doesn't do this?

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy because you've applied the subtotal class only in the inner table

Answer (score 1):

`table.mainTable td` has a background color of `#D0D7DF` set which is overriding the style on the `tr`

You need to add the in-line style to the `TD` or create a css rule such as

```
.subtotal td
{
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

Comment: I see, due the reasons mentioned by @bfrohs your use of !important higher up the document stopped it from working.